# Prevent Site loning in multiple iframes on single page

Tags: java, html

How can i block multiple iframes. For example my site is newwebsite.com
other people show my site inframe on their pages multiple time. I want to load website in first iframe only and disable all othe iframe. like given below

```
<iframe src="https://crypto2u.xyz/invite?ref=1693" style="width:1000px; height:500px" frameborder='0'></iframe>

<iframe src="https://crypto2u.xyz/invite?ref=1693" style="width:1000px; height:500px" frameborder='0'></iframe>

<iframe src="https://crypto2u.xyz/invite?ref=1693" style="width:1000px; height:500px" frameborder='0'></iframe>

<iframe src="https://crypto2u.xyz/invite?ref=1693" style="width:1000px; height:500px" frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

what should i do to open the site only in first frame and not in all other frames or error of mutiple frames

I have tries sameorigion but it blocks all frames from thirdparty sites. I want to show single frmae on single page.

Comment: How is this related to Java? Did you mean JavaScript a totally different programming language and environment?